# Oracle Stored Procedure not working, likely because of syntax

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I know I am an idiot.. But I have been trying to create this simple stored procedure in my Oracle database for some time now and I keep getting the error "procedure created with compilation errors". I can't seem to find anything wrong with it and I am following the syntax I have found online. I am using an Oracle xe 11g server with pl/sql 11. Please help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hr.countEmployee(passin IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hr.mitch_employee_motors WHERE hr.mitch_employee_motors.deptno = hr.countemployee.passin;
END;
```

Comment: a SELECT requires an INTO in PLSQL.

Comment: You can always check user_errors (or all_errors/dba_errors as applicable) to find out the error that has occurred with that procedure. That should give you a much better chance to fix the problem if your GUI/IDE/CLI is not outputting useful error information on compilation.

Comment: If the procedure is created in the `hr` schema then there is no need to prefix all the `hr` table references with the schema owner. In fact it's generally considered good practice not to. I would generally avoid hardcoding the schema owner for the procedure too, but that will depend on your build process. Also, there is no such thing as *'pl/sql 11'*.

Comment: By the way, *not working* and *not compiling* and generally two different things.

Answer (score 3):

Aleksej hit the nail on the head and I follow up with the code that reflects his comment.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hr.countemployee (passin IN NUMBER)
IS
   l_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO l_count
     FROM hr.mitch_employee_motors
    WHERE hr.mitch_employee_motors.deptno = hr.countemployee.passin;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_count);
END;
```

What are you using the write and execute your SQL and PL/SQL? I encourage you to try out [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html). It would have helped you a whole lot in diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hr.countEmployee(passin IN NUMBER,OUT_CURSOR OUT  sys_refcursor)
    IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hr.mitch_employee_motors WHERE hr.mitch_employee_motors.deptno = hr.countemployee.passin;
    END;
```